# How to stop this transition when navigating to a new screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to stop this transition on navigating to another screen?
[image: navigation]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend usage of GetX library to make navigation and all it's properties so easy to use.

https://pub.dev/packages/get

this code will navigate to another screen:

```
Get.to(Page())
```

and here is transition with no animation:

```
Get.to(
  () => ProfilePage(),
  fullscreenDialog: false,
  popGesture: true,
  transition: Transition.noTransition,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can used this code to stop transition animation  using  PageRouteBuilder for navigation**

> here is the example try this

```
 Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        PageRouteBuilder(
                          pageBuilder: (_, ani, ani1) => HomeMain(),
                          transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 0),
                        ),
                      );
```